# custom directive doesn't work on code inserted by Renderer2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have following directive

```
import {
  Directive,
  HostBinding,
  PLATFORM_ID,
  Inject,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Directive({
  selector: 'a[href]'
})
export class ChangeUrlDirective {

  @HostBinding('attr.rel') relAttr = '';
  @HostBinding('attr.target') targetAttr = '';
  @HostBinding('attr.href') hrefAttr = '';
  @Input() href: string;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string, private router: Router) {}

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log("hi")
    this.hrefAttr = this.href;

  }




}
```

I have code which works with angular code. However, When I insert HTML code using Renderer2

```
    <span #htmlContainer></span>
```

My custom directive directive don't work on this insert HTML code.

Any one knows why it is not working and how to fix it.

Comment: how do you insert that html? do you somehow process it to enable custom directive logic?

Comment: use following code to insert HTML 

```        this.renderer.setProperty(this.htmlContainer.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', HTML_CODE);
```

Comment: I want to update any URL that has relative path no matter where they are in html code.

Comment: directives doesnt work for  innerHTML bindings